# JavaScript Caluculation Array [a,b] + [c,d]

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code and tested it.
const test = [1,2] + [1,1]
Output of test was

> "1,21,1"
>   ???

What does  "1,21,1"  stand for?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4h98Lo5x/

Comment: "*What does "1,21,1" stand for?*" the result of concatenating the two arrays. It's (essentially) `[1,2].toString() + [1,1].toString()` ->  `[1,2].join(",") + [1,1].join(",")` -> `"1,2" + "1,1"` -> `"1,21,1"`